# Highlight individual value in facet tile plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to highlight the minimum BIC value in a faceted tile plot by either drawing a box around it or an arrow pointing to it.

```
set.seed(1000)
tseries<-data.frame("value"=rnorm(300, 50, 7.5))
BICs<- apply(expand.grid(0:2,0:2,0:2),1L,
               function(rw)BIC(arima(tseries$value,order=rw)))
ARIMA<-expand.grid(0:2,0:2,0:2)
names(ARIMA)<-c("p","d","q")
ARIMA$BICs<-BICs
ARIMA$d<-paste("d=",ARIMA$d,sep="")

ggplot(ARIMA, aes(x=q, y=p)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = BICs)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(BICs,2)),colour="yellow",fontface="bold",size=4) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "cyan", high = "blue4")+ 
  facet_wrap(~d,nrow=2)
```

[image: smallest value is the ARIMA(p=1,d=1,q=1) specification]

poking around stack it seems like the best solution for drawing a box around a single value would be to call a new data frame with the right rectangle aesthetics

```
best<-data.frame("xmin"=ARIMA[which(ARIMA$BICs==min(ARIMA$BICs)),3]-.5,
                      "xmax"=ARIMA[which(ARIMA$BICs==min(ARIMA$BICs)),3]+.5,
                      "ymin"=ARIMA[which(ARIMA$BICs==min(ARIMA$BICs)),1]-.5,
                      "ymax"=ARIMA[which(ARIMA$BICs==min(ARIMA$BICs)),1]+.5,
                      "d"=ARIMA[which(ARIMA$BICs==min(ARIMA$BICs)),2],
                      "BIC"=ARIMA[which(ARIMA$BICs==min(ARIMA$BICs)),4])
best$d<-factor(best$d,levels=levels(as.factor(ARIMA$d)))
```

but it spits out errors when I try to put geom_rect aesthetic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have just made the p q vector in the arima best data frame

```
best<-data.frame("q"=ARIMA[which(ARIMA$BICs==min(ARIMA$BICs)),3],
                 "p"=ARIMA[which(ARIMA$BICs==min(ARIMA$BICs)),1],
                 "d"=ARIMA[which(ARIMA$BICs==min(ARIMA$BICs)),2],
                 "BIC"=ARIMA[which(ARIMA$BICs==min(ARIMA$BICs)),4])
best$d<-factor(best$d,levels=levels(as.factor(ARIMA$d)))
```

and then the geom_rect works as usual

```
geom_rect(data=best,aes(xmin=q-.5,xmax=q+.5,ymin=p-.5,ymax=p+.5),colour="yellow",alpha=0)
```

[image]